# Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Permission denied

Tags: performance, bluetooth

00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 is a headset.

> sdptool search --bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 HS

results in

```
Searching for HS on 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 ...
Service Name: Headset
Service RecHandle: 0x10001
Service Class ID List:
  "Headset" (0x1108)
  "Generic Audio" (0x1203)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 2
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Headset" (0x1108)
    Version: 0x0100
```

I try this:

> sudo rfcomm connect 0 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 2

I get

> Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Permission denied

```
hcidump -X
```

shows

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 2.4
device: hci0 snap_len: 1028 filter: 0xffffffff
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13
    bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 ptype 0xcc18 rswitch 0x01 clkoffset 0x0000
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11
    status 0x00 handle 12 bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 type ACL encrypt 0x00
< HCI Command: Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) plen 2
    handle 12
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Page Scan Repetition Mode Change (0x20) plen 7
    bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 mode 1
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3
    handle 12 slots 5
> HCI Event: Read Remote Supported Features (0x0b) plen 11
    status 0x00 handle 12
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0f 0xc6 0x8b 0xef 0x59 0x83
< HCI Command: Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) plen 3
    handle 12 page 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Read Remote Extended Features (0x23) plen 13
    status 0x00 handle 12 page 1 max 1
    Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
< HCI Command: Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) plen 10
    bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 mode 2 clkoffset 0x0000
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Remote Name Req Complete (0x07) plen 255
    status 0x00 bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 name 'Iqua Slim'
< HCI Command: Authentication Requested (0x01|0x0011) plen 2
    handle 12
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Authentication Requested (0x01|0x0011) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Link Key Request (0x17) plen 6
    bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66
< HCI Command: Link Key Request Reply (0x01|0x000b) plen 22
    bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66 key ED0F049830ECE5F990ED4C0AE6C2AF82
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10
    Link Key Request Reply (0x01|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 bdaddr 00:1A:7D:11:C0:66
> HCI Event: Auth Complete (0x06) plen 3
    status 0x05 handle 12
    Error: Authentication Failure
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3
    handle 12 reason 0x13
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 12 reason 0x16
    Reason: Connection Terminated by Local Host
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Could you post the output of `rfcomm` ? Also, could it be a PIN issue?